# Do dnf updates conflicts with gnome software center updates?

Tags: fedora, gnome, upgrade, gnome3, dnf

I'm using fedora 25 gnome latest update. My dnf repo list is

```
fedora-cisco-openh264.repo  rpmfusion-free-updates.repo
fedora.repo                 rpmfusion-free-updates-testing.repo
fedora-spotify.repo         rpmfusion-nonfree-rawhide.repo
fedora-updates.repo         rpmfusion-nonfree.repo
google-chrome.repo          rpmfusion-nonfree-updates.repo
rpmfusion-free.repo         rpmfusion-nonfree-updates-testing.repo
```

Yesterday I updated my system using dnf. Today gnome software center notified me that 19 packages need to be updated. I tried to update using dnf because I hate updating using the software center since it requires restart but couldn't find any update using `dnf update`.

So I updated fedora using gnome software center, it installed a buggy gdm version, couldn't log in, had to use `tty` to login, then `startx`.

I do `sudo dnf distro-sync` then dnf deletes and downgrades all updates that gnome software center had installed, I reboot and everything works.

Gnome software center is a mastery to me, not the fist time I ask about it on this site. Is it trustworthy? Do its repos conflict with dnf?

Comment: @mattdm nice catch! you should work as a detective :) thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GUI on Fedora Workstation uses PackageKit to install OS packages.  PackageKit on Fedora uses the exact same repos specified in `/etc/yum.repos.d`.

It's also possible to use PackageKit through `pkcon` instead.  It doesn't necessarily provide much detail in normal operation.  There are some tools you could look at though:

- `pkcon get-updates` - list updates without installing
- `pkcon refresh force` - refresh list of updates / packages
- `pkcon update` - installs updates, without rebooting, or stopping any programs running the previous version.
- `pkcon resolve gdm` - if there are multiple available gdm packages (including updates), the documentation says it's supposed to list them all.  Apparently this is a lie and it doesn't list updates though.  https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1429488

PackageKit bypasses `dnf`.  They do share a significant amount of code through a number of libraries.  However it's glued together and configured differently, for example it uses a completely separate cache.  It even handles signature verification differently (AFAIK, dnf mainly delegates this to rpm).

FWIW, I haven't seen PackageKit cause any such problem while using Fedora Workstation.  The main issues I've had with PackageKit has been it not notifying about updates.

My Fedora 25 system reports the following:

```
$ dnf repolist
Last metadata expiration check: 0:16:16 ago on Mon Mar  6 12:50:41 2017.
repo id                                                        repo name                                                                        status
fedora                                                         Fedora 25 - x86_64                                                               51,669
local-google-chrome                                            local-google-chrome                                                                   3
*rpmfusion-free                                                RPM Fusion for Fedora 25 - Free                                                     541
*rpmfusion-free-updates                                        RPM Fusion for Fedora 25 - Free - Updates                                           170
updates                                                        Fedora 25 - x86_64 - Updates                                                     17,151

$ dnf info gdm | grep -E 'Version|Repo'
Version     : 3.22.1
Repo        : @System
Version     : 3.22.2
Repo        : updates
Version     : 3.22.2
Repo        : updates

$ pkcon refresh force
...

$ pkcon get-updates | grep gdm
Available    gdm-1:3.22.2-1.fc25.x86_64 (updates)
```

(and the `pkcon resolve` bug:)

```
$ pkcon resolve gdm
Resolving                     [=========================]         
Installed       gdm-1:3.22.1-1.fc25.x86_64 (installed:anaconda)                 The GNOME Display Manager
Available       gdm-1:3.22.1-1.fc25.i686 (fedora)                               The GNOME Display Manager
```

Comment: I'll try to refresh the list maybe that would fix it. `.. I've had with PackageKit has been it not notifying about updates` I faced that and fixed it by removing a repo or two from dnf, also by running dnf clean all